# Tumblr Post Background Images Outside div?

Tags: html, css, background

I want to make it so that each individual post on my Tumblr has multiple background images that are outside the post div. I've made an example [here](http://static.tumblr.com/tc2d7hp/CLgnesiuk/bg-example.png). I know how to make multiple-outside-div-backgrounds for fixed elements, but I want these to be able to apply to all posts, regardless of size. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. At the moment, your question lacks effort. Can you please show what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/a8mhz4qh/

HTML:

```
<div class="post-container">
    <div class="post">
         <h2>Title</h2>

        <p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</p>
        <p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</p>
        <p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.post-container {
    background: url(http://openphoto.net/volumes/sizes/miro/24396/2.jpg) 0 0/100% auto no-repeat;
    padding: 70px 15px;
    width: 750px;
}
.post {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .85);
    padding: 10px;
}
```